# Matrix extracted from list keep list data type

Tags: r, matrix, reshape2

I have a list composed by just one matrix:

```
$`1`
                   Buy  C-Level_3RDLIVE   C-Level_3RDWP   C-Level_AR   C-Level_ARCHWEB   C-Level_ASKOD   C-Level_CR 
 Buy                 0         0.1818182       0.0000000            0                 0               0            0
 C-Level_3RDLIVE     0         0.0000000       0.0000000            0                 0               0            0
 C-Level_3RDWP       0         0.0000000       0.1111111            1                 0               0            0
 C-Level_AR          0         0.0000000       0.0000000            0                 0               0            0
 C-Level_ARCHWEB     0         0.0000000       0.0000000            0                 0               0            1
```

The matrix it is derived from the "fitMarkovchain" function of the "clickstream" package:

```
#fit the model
mc <- fitMarkovChain(clickstreamList = cls, order = 1,
                     control = list(optimizer = "quadratic"))
mc

#extract list of matrix
tr<-mc@transitions
```

My objective is to have the above matrix reshaped vertically, with the rows/labels names and probabilities each in a separate column. I have tried the following:

```
tr<-tr[[1]]
rwn<-rownames(tr)
as.data.frame(t(as.matrix((tr))))
```

But it seems the tr object keep the list data type despite the as.matrix transformation.

The desired output is:

```
x1   x2                  %
Buy Buy                  0
Buy C-level_3Rdlive      0.1818182
..  ..                   ..
```

Any hint about how to remove the list type and reshaped the matrix vertically?

But the tr object is

Comment: Why do you need the `as.matrix` part before `t`ransposing? Plus, the result doesn't appear to be a list at least using `iris`. It is a `data.frame` object. `t` is perhaps not the function you need anyways?

Comment: The type is classified as list: > typeof(tr)
[1] "list" . It is the outcome of the function "fitMarkovChain" of the package "clickstream"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is already a matrix, then you can directly use `t()` for the transpose. I am not sure if things below are what you want

```
t(tr)
```

such that

```
> t(tr)
                      Buy C-Level_3RDLIVE C-Level_3RDWP C-Level_AR C-Level_ARCHWEB
Buy             0.0000000               0     0.0000000          0               0
C-Level_3RDLIVE 0.1818182               0     0.0000000          0               0
C-Level_3RDWP   0.0000000               0     0.1111111          0               0
C-Level_AR      0.0000000               0     1.0000000          0               0
C-Level_ARCHWEB 0.0000000               0     0.0000000          0               0
C-Level_ASKOD   0.0000000               0     0.0000000          0               0
C-Level_CR      0.0000000               0     0.0000000          0               1
```

**DATA**

```
tr <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1818182, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1111111, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1), .Dim = c(5L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(c("Buy", "C-Level_3RDLIVE", 
"C-Level_3RDWP", "C-Level_AR", "C-Level_ARCHWEB"), c("Buy", "C-Level_3RDLIVE", 
"C-Level_3RDWP", "C-Level_AR", "C-Level_ARCHWEB", "C-Level_ASKOD", 
"C-Level_CR")))
```

Here is the code to reshape your table

```
X <- data.frame(rev(expand.grid(rownames(tr),colnames(tr))),val = as.vector(t(tr)))
```

such that

```
> X
              Var2            Var1              val
1              Buy             Buy        0.0000000
2              Buy C-Level_3RDLIVE        0.1818182
3              Buy   C-Level_3RDWP        0.0000000
4              Buy      C-Level_AR        0.0000000
5              Buy C-Level_ARCHWEB        0.0000000
6  C-Level_3RDLIVE             Buy        0.0000000
7  C-Level_3RDLIVE C-Level_3RDLIVE        0.0000000
8  C-Level_3RDLIVE   C-Level_3RDWP        0.0000000
9  C-Level_3RDLIVE      C-Level_AR        0.0000000
10 C-Level_3RDLIVE C-Level_ARCHWEB        0.0000000
11   C-Level_3RDWP             Buy        0.0000000
12   C-Level_3RDWP C-Level_3RDLIVE        0.0000000
13   C-Level_3RDWP   C-Level_3RDWP        0.0000000
14   C-Level_3RDWP      C-Level_AR        0.0000000
15   C-Level_3RDWP C-Level_ARCHWEB        0.0000000
16      C-Level_AR             Buy        0.0000000
17      C-Level_AR C-Level_3RDLIVE        0.1111111
18      C-Level_AR   C-Level_3RDWP        1.0000000
19      C-Level_AR      C-Level_AR        0.0000000
20      C-Level_AR C-Level_ARCHWEB        0.0000000
21 C-Level_ARCHWEB             Buy        0.0000000
22 C-Level_ARCHWEB C-Level_3RDLIVE        0.0000000
23 C-Level_ARCHWEB   C-Level_3RDWP        0.0000000
24 C-Level_ARCHWEB      C-Level_AR        0.0000000
25 C-Level_ARCHWEB C-Level_ARCHWEB        0.0000000
26   C-Level_ASKOD             Buy        0.0000000
27   C-Level_ASKOD C-Level_3RDLIVE        0.0000000
28   C-Level_ASKOD   C-Level_3RDWP        0.0000000
29   C-Level_ASKOD      C-Level_AR        0.0000000
30   C-Level_ASKOD C-Level_ARCHWEB        0.0000000
31      C-Level_CR             Buy        0.0000000
32      C-Level_CR C-Level_3RDLIVE        0.0000000
33      C-Level_CR   C-Level_3RDWP        0.0000000
34      C-Level_CR      C-Level_AR        0.0000000
35      C-Level_CR C-Level_ARCHWEB        1.0000000
```

Comment: It seems that when extracted from the list, the Matrix keep the "list" type despite being a Matrix

Comment: @davidecortellino what do you mean by `the Matrix keep the "list" type despite being a Matrix`?

Comment: I mean that in the package description the "transition" object is declared as matrix. however, when the object is extracted from the list of outcomes and assigned to the "tr" object, the typeof(tr) function  returns "list"